# Map $f:S^2 \to S^1$ with $f(-x) = -f(x)$

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Consider a continuous function $f:S^2 \to S^1$ with $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in S^2$. I intend to show that such map doesn't exist using topological covering/lifting theory.

Here my attempts: If we assump that such function $f$ exists then since $S^2$ simply connected and $\mathbb{R}$ is a covering of $S^1$ there exist a lift map $g: S^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with property $f = p \circ g$. Here  $p: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ is the canonical covering map.

Then I tried to consider a path $\gamma:[0,1] \to S^2$ with property $\gamma(0)= -\gamma(1)$, therefore $\gamma(0), \gamma(1)$ are antipodal.

And therefore (by property of $f$) also holds $f(\gamma(0)) = f(-\gamma(1)) = -f(\gamma(1))$.

I guess that considering this property one can deduce a contradiction by considering a lift $\widetilde{\omega}:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ of the path $\omega:= f \circ \gamma$.

Can anybody explain what here goes wrong/ how to get the desired contradiction? Intiutively I guess that something goest wrong with the uniquess of the lift (see homotopy lifting prop)... but I don't find this last step.

Another attempt of mine would be to cosider the new path $\omega^2$ which is obviously a loop. Can I get a contradiction by considering the lift of it? Should the lift be also a Loop? Why?

Remark: As in a comment stated below this problem is a special case of Borsum Ulam and can be proved rigorously using homological methods. The intention of this question how to prove the statement for $n=2$ with toolbox from elementary lifting properties / covering theory.

Comment: This is a particular case of one of the enunciates of Borsuk-Ulam's theorem. See p. 12 of https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~nevoe/homepage/TopMethNotes-1Sam.pdf

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reference. I modified the formulation of the question now since the main point of my interest was to prove it with toolbox from lifting theory. Sorry for unprecise formulation of the question.

Comment: See too the book https://www.amazon.com/Using-Borsuk-Ulam-Theorem-Combinatorics-Universitext/dp/3540003622

Comment: Technical point- If I recall correctly, I think you need that $S^2$ is simply connected, not just that $S^2$ is connected, to lift $f:S^2\to S^1$ to a map $\tilde{f}:S^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Neal: 
Yes that's true. I fixed it. I suppose that under this conditions it suffice to show that $\omega^2$ isn't a nullhomotopic loop. This would be absurd since it factorize through simply connected $S^2$ by construction. So the desired contradiction. But to show that $\omega^2$ isn't nullhomotopic we need that it's (unique) lift in $\mathbb{R}$ isn't a loop. Here I'm stuck.

Comment: A couple of thoughts - I don't have the details worked out so I'm not posting as an answer. The property on $f$ holds $\forall x$ so you should be searching for particular $x$. In that vein I'm pretty sure the property on $f$ implies that the image of a great circle under $f$ is not nullhomotopic. So the image of a great circle under the lift of $f$ will be the lift of a non-nullhomotopic curve, which will immediately yield a contradiction to the well-definedness of the lift of $f$.

Comment: @Neal: Thank you for the idea. Some requests: By "great circe" you mean an arbitrary nontrivial intersection of $S^2$ with a plane? And the second: Why the last step provides a contradiction to well definedness of the lift? You mean in the sense that the lift is by construction null homotopic?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz Yes, that is what I mean by "great circle." The last step provides a contradiction to well definedness because $\widetilde{f\circ\gamma}(1) = \widetilde{f\circ\gamma}(0) + 1$ but $\widetilde{f}\circ\gamma(1) = \widetilde{f}\circ\gamma(0)$ since $\gamma(1) = \gamma(0)$ (here I use $\widetilde{*}$ to denote lift).

Comment: @Neal: So in sence of that one lifting is a loop but the other not. So uniqueness problem. One step isn't clear: How do you get $\widetilde{f\circ\gamma}(1) = \widetilde{f\circ\gamma}(0) + 1$ especially the $1$?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz one last comment before a mod yells at us to move to chat: it doesn't need to be $+1$ I think. Since the curve is not nullhomotopic, the start point of the lift is a nontrivial deck transformation away from the end point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that there exists a map $f$ as in your question.

We regard $S^1$ as the equator of $S^2$. Then $g = f \mid_{S^1} : S^1 \to S^1$ is inessential because it extends to $D^2$ (identified with the upper hemisphere of $S^2$). We have $g(-z) = -g(z)$. Let $p : \mathbb{R} \to S^1, p(t) = e^{it}$, denote the standard covering map.

Since $g$ is inessential, it lifts to $\tilde{g} : S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$. Define $h(z) = \tilde{g}(z) - \tilde{g}(-z)$. Then
$$e^{ih(z)} = e^{i\tilde{g}(z) - i\tilde{g}(-z)} = e^{i\tilde{g}(z)}/e^{i\tilde{g}(-z)} = g(z)/g(-z) = -1 .$$
Hence $h(z)  \in \{ (2k+1)\pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Because $h$ is continuous and $S^1$ is connected, we see that $h(z)$ is constant with value $(2k+1)\pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Being constant, $h$ has the property $h(z) = h(-z)$ for all $z$. From the definiton we see that $h(-z) = -h(z)$ which implies $h(z) = 0$ for all $z$. Hence $0 = (2k+1)\pi$, i.e. $k = -1/2$, which is absurd.

Comment: Dear @Paul Frost, could you please explain how the map $g$ being inessentioal, leads to the fact that it can be lifted to $\tilde{g}$? Is there a particular theorem?

Comment: @Inez This follows from the lifting theorem for covering projections. Do you have some knowledge about covering projections?

Comment: I know some basics about lifting and covering maps but nothing about covering projections. I just searched and read some definitions and theorems regarding covering projections here: https://math.mit.edu/~hrm/18.905/covering.pdf.

Comment: @Inez Have a look into [Hatcher](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).